# How do I get a tkinter box to show up in another tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, messagebox

I'm trying to make a GUI for a password storage and hashing system, but I have hit a roadblock. I am having 2 buttons, one to log in, and one to make an account. When the login button is clicked, a new tkinter window opens with the login page. however, the login button is supposed to show on the second page, but it doesn't, and I have no clue why. Here is the code for the full system:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import*

username = ("Tom")
password = ("test") 
usernameguess1 = ("")
passwordguess1 = ("")


def trylogin():
   print ("Trying to login...")
   if usernameguess.get() == username:
       print ("Complete sucsessfull!")
       messagebox.showinfo("Sucess ", "Successfully logged in.")
   else:
       print ("Error: (Incorrect value entered)")
       messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Sorry, but your username or password is incorrect. Try again")

def loginpage():
    #Gui Formatting
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    window.title("HasherTest_V0.1 Login")
    window.geometry("300x150")

    #Username and password boxes
    usernametext = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username:")
    usernameguess = tkinter.Entry(window)
    passwordtext = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password:")
    passwordguess = tkinter.Entry(window, show="*")

    usernameguess1 = usernameguess

    #login button

    attemptlogin = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=trylogin)

    usernametext.pack()
    usernameguess.pack()
    passwordtext.pack()
    passwordguess.pack()
    attemptlogin.pack()
    window.mainloop()


#Gui Formatting (again)
window = tkinter.Tk() 
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.title("HasherTest_V0.1")
window.geometry("300x150")

loginbutton = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=loginpage)
loginbutton.pack()
```

And here is the code for just the second window on its own. For some reason I have to import tkinter message boxes aswell, or my IDLE errors out.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

username = ("Tom")
password = ("test") 
usernameguess1 = ("")
passwordguess1 = ("")


def trylogin():
   print ("Trying to login...")
   if usernameguess.get() == username:
       print ("Complete sucsessfull!")
       messagebox.showinfo("Sucess ", "Successfully logged in.")
   else:
       print ("Error: (Incorrect value entered)")
       messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Sorry, but your username or password is incorrect. Try again")

#Gui Formatting
window = tkinter.Tk() 
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.title("HasherTest_V0.1 Login")
window.geometry("300x150")


#Username and password boxes
usernametext = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username:")
usernameguess = tkinter.Entry(window)
passwordtext = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password:")
passwordguess = tkinter.Entry(window, show="*")

usernameguess1 = usernameguess

#login button
attemptlogin = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=trylogin)

usernametext.pack()
usernameguess.pack()
passwordtext.pack()
passwordguess.pack()
attemptlogin.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I saw multiple calls to `Tk()` in your code - and stopped looking at it; nothing can possibly work right in such a situation.  You have to use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper um ok, I am new to tkinter, but could you tell me how to do this? maybe copy and edit my code to show me how?

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759)
and [When to use the Toplevel Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. I completely reworked your code, and it works(as far as I can tell).

I completely removed the `textvariable` and `StringVar()`. They aren't needed. The reason your code wasn't working is because you check the name of the file "string", but you need to add ".txt" in order to get a perfect equality.

Code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import*

from tkinter import messagebox

username = ("Tom")
password = ("test") 
usernameguess1 = ("")
passwordguess1 = ("")



def loginpage():
    #Gui Formatting
    root = tkinter.Toplevel()
    #root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    root.title("HasherTest_V0.1 Login")
    root.geometry("300x150")

    #Username and password boxes
    usernametext = tkinter.Label(root, text="Username:")
    usernameguess = tkinter.Entry(root)
    passwordtext = tkinter.Label(root, text="Password:")
    passwordguess = tkinter.Entry(root, show="*")

    usernameguess1 = usernameguess
    def trylogin():
        print ("Trying to login...")
        if usernameguess.get() == username:
           print ("Complete sucsessfull!")
           messagebox.showinfo("Sucess ", "Successfully logged in.")
        else:
            print ("Error: (Incorrect value entered)")
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Sorry, but your username or password is incorrect. Try again")
        #login button

    attemptlogin = tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=trylogin)

    usernametext.pack()
    usernameguess.pack()
    passwordtext.pack()
    passwordguess.pack()
    attemptlogin.pack()
    window.mainloop()


#Gui Formatting (again)
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.title("HasherTest_V0.1")
window.geometry("300x150")

loginbutton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", command=loginpage)
loginbutton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I also took the liberty to, as @stovfl mentioned, add `Toplevel()` instances instead of using `Tk()` multiple times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Tf0R24 No Prob ^^

Comment: Happy to help. .

Comment: This answer would be better if you added a description of the important change. Otherwise we have to compare your code line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.